# Adding a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm not sure if this is feasible or not, but I want to add a simple custom post type that does two(2) jobs:

1. Has a comment section (the user can comment on an image)
2. It has a rating system (basic 5 stars rating)

So the idea is that the custom post type is an image that has the above properties I upload the image on my end and the user can see the image and rate it and/or comment on it

Is there a possible way I can achieve this custom post type?

Comment: Sure, there are lots of ways. What have you tried so far? Are you planning to custom code this or are you looking for plugins that may help you set this up?

Comment: I have used Custom Post Type UI and ACF(Advanced Custom Fields) Plugins, to build the post and fields and used Elementor to style it with a loop and a single post type and archive. where I'm actually stuck is giving the user (logged in user) the ability to coment and rate the images but not upload images. it's me who will upload the images you get it?